# How do I disable the automatic restoring of open software after an update in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

When Windows updates overnight on my work machine the next time I login it loads all the apps I had open before the update. I usually have a fair amount of apps open so it takes several minutes to restore. I'd rather start from scratch. I don't have any control over the update process.  Is there a way to disable this auto-restore feature separately?

Comment: Close the apps before you let it do an update :)

Comment: I've never seen Windows restoring the apps that had been open while Microsoft Update restarted the computer after having installed the updates.

Answer (score -1):

Stop and disable Windows updates service:

```
sc stop wuauserv
sc config wuauserv start= disabled
```

Restore:

```
sc config wuauserv start= auto
sc start wuauserv
```

Manual:

```
sc config wuauserv start= demand
```

if need update, run:

```
sc start wuauserv
```

Comment: Why doesn't he just set Window Update to prompt him to install any updates that are released instead?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows update service behavior sometimes changes by the manufacturer. And with very unpleasant effects. In this case, I will not prevent this change under any circumstances. When I want I will update the system. Thx!

Comment: @Ramhound http://www.infoworld.com/t/microsoft-windows/obscure-setting-gives-users-more-control-over-windows-auto-reboots-216160 Obscure setting gives users more control over Windows auto-reboots. Always happy for those who have no problems. Well, or those who are about them, never heard of.

Comment: @Ramhound I can not imagine why in article tags: Microsoft Windows, Patch Management, Microsoft, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Vista, Windows XP. Probably because someone is reading too fast).